# SQLite query - date reserved word?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Am just curious, is `date` a reserved word i `SQLite`? I have a column which is named date, and trying to run this query:

```
DELETE FROM cases WHERE date <= date('now','-1 day')
```

By doing this:

```
String query = "DELETE FROM cases WHERE date <= date('now','-1 day')";

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); 

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        boolean found = cursor.moveToFirst(); 
        if(found) {
            int result = cursor.getCount();
            Log.w("DeleteOldCases: ", "Result: " + Integer.toString(result));
            db.close();
        }
```

But the cursor just gives me a false back, when calling `moveToFirst`. But in my database there are actually rows that are older than one day. Can anybody explain whats wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: I think so, as it is also a type while doing CREATE TABLE, but easy to try out and change it right?

Comment: btw, i think quoting it would solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it seems to be a reserved word.

look at: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

```
 date(timestring, modifier, modifier, ...)
```

It's strange to have a cursors form DELETE statement. Try to split the operation in

```
SELECT * FROM cases WHERE date <= date('now','-1 day')
```

then execute your checks

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); 
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
boolean found = cursor.moveToFirst(); 
if(found) {
    int result = cursor.getCount();
    Log.w("DeleteOldCases: ", "Result: " + Integer.toString(result));
    db.close();
}
```

and then execute the DELETE part

```
DELETE FROM cases WHERE date <= date('now','-1 day')
```

Comment: But I can create the database, and do different queries on it. So maybe not?

Comment: Could you try to use [table.field] to identify the column?

Comment: I did actually work as I originally wrote it, but the cursor return false anyway. Strange..

Comment: A cursor from delete statement? I never used cursor in that way! The query does not return a set of results so the cursor can't move

Comment: So the problem can be solved as I wrote in the answer, by splitting the job in SELECT and DELETE?

Comment: Your approach would work, haven't tried it but it looks like this is a way to go.

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite old but it deserves a proper answer.

No, `date` is **not** a reserved word.

The problem with your code is that you are using the method [`rawQuery()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#rawQuery(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20android.os.CancellationSignal)) to delete from the table, which is not the way to do it.
`rawQuery()` should be used to return rows from the table in the form of a `Cursor` object.
Since your sql statement does not return any rows the method `moveToFirst()` returns `false`.

What you should use is the method [`delete()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#delete(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D)) which returns the number of deleted rows:

```
int result = db.delete("cases", "date <= date('now', '-1 day')", null);
```