# sqlite query to return records from last month and this month both returning records from this month

Tags: sql, flutter, sqlite, dart

I have two functions where the first one is supposed to return the records for this month and the second one is suppsoed to return the records from last month, but they are both returning the records for this month.

```cs
static Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getThisMonthItems() async {
    final db = await SQLHelper.db(); //get connection
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    String query =
        "SELECT * FROM sets WHERE date BETWEEN datetime('now', 'start of month', 'start of day') AND datetime('now', 'localtime');";
    
    return db.rawQuery(query);
}

static Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getLastMonthtems() async {
    final db = await SQLHelper.db(); //get connection
    String query =
        "SELECT * FROM sets WHERE date BETWEEN datetime('now','start of month','-1 month') AND datetime('now','localtime', 'start of month');";

    return db.rawQuery(query);
}
```

And here is the schema:

```cs
static Future<void> createTables(sql.Database database) async {
    await database.execute("""CREATE TABLE sets(
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
        exercise_name TEXT,
        total_weight TEXT,
        total_reps TEXT,
        date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        is_favorite INTEGER)""");
    print('Database created');
}
```

I was expecting the first function to return sets from this month and the second function to return sets from the last month up until the start of this month. Also, sets from the first day of the month are not getting returning in either function.

Method to insert record into database:

```cs
//method to create an item to insert into the database table
static Future<int> createItem(
    String exercise_name,
    String? total_weight,
    String? total_reps,
) async {
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    String formattedDate = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(now);
    
    final db = await SQLHelper.db(); //opening the database
    final data = {
      'exercise_name': exercise_name,
      'total_weight': total_weight,
      'total_reps': total_reps,
      'date': formattedDate,
      'is_favorite': 0
    }; //making map to insert
    final id = await db.insert(
        //inserting that data map
        'sets',
        data, //items is table name and data is the map we made
        conflictAlgorithm: sql
            .ConflictAlgorithm.replace); //best practice to prevent duplicates
    return id;
}
```

Comment: You should use the `localtime` modifier consistently.

Comment: What do you mean

Comment: @MarkBenningfield what do think the inconsistency in `localtime` modifier here since `datetime(datetimestring, [modifier1, modifier2…, modifierN])` function takes only one mandatory argument and rest is optional modifers specially with `Now` and `localtime`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you do you a SELECT query to first retrieve few records to examine your datetime stamps?
I am also guessing `date` column name is a keyword in SQLLite. You may want to check it and change the column name.

Here's what your current DATE BETWEEN clauses in the query produce in terms of dates format. I used a SQLFiddle with sample data with SQLLite(SQL.js) version. [Click here to see the SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/32d4acb/9). (Next time you can use that to create, insert your sample tables and your query.)

```
/*datetime(datetimestring, [modifier1, modifier2…, modifierN])*/
SELECT datetime('now') as 'Current date & time';

Current date & time
2023-05-03 12:18:46

SELECT datetime('now', 'start of month', 'start of day'), 
datetime('now', 'localtime')
;

datetime('now', 'start of month', 'start of day')   
2023-05-01 00:00:00     

datetime('now', 'localtime')
2023-05-03 22:18:46


SELECT datetime('now','start of month','-1 month'),
datetime('now','localtime', 'start of month')
;

datetime('now','start of month','-1 month')     
2023-04-01 00:00:00

datetime('now','localtime', 'start of month')
2023-05-01 00:00:00

/*NOTE THAT MY SAMPLE TABLE DATE FORMAT IS '2023-04-25' YYYY-MM-DD. 
Therefore it was formatted to your schema dateformat; it seems to produce 
records without an issue. I am only looking at your dateformat.*/

SELECT * FROM s
WHERE datetime(sdate) BETWEEN
datetime('now','start of month','-1 month') AND
datetime('now','localtime', 'start of month')
;

/*last month to current month. Note my date format*/
sid     tid     sdate       moneyD  moneyC
1       21      2023-04-25  1000    0
2       22      2023-05-01  0       100

SELECT * FROM s
WHERE datetime(sdate) BETWEEN
datetime('now', 'start of month', 'start of day') AND 
datetime('now', 'localtime')
;

/*current month*/
sid     tid     sdate       moneyD  moneyC
2       22      2023-05-01  0       100
```

Funny enough, `date` is a [reserved word/keyword in sqllite too. See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17399781/1389394)

> I was expecting the first function to return sets from this month and the second function to return sets from the last month up until the start of this month, also sets from the first day of the month are not getting returning in either function

This is how to include last day of the last month in the select query: 'now','start of month','-1 day.

```
SELECT datetime('now','start of month','-1 month'),
datetime('now','start of month','-1 day')
;

datetime('now','start of month','-1 month')
2023-04-01 00:00:00         
datetime('now','start of month','-1 day')
2023-04-30 00:00:00

SELECT * FROM s
WHERE datetime(sdate) BETWEEN
datetime('now','start of month','-1 month') AND
datetime('now','start of month','-1 day')
;

sid     tid     sdate       moneyD  moneyC
1       21      2023-04-25  1000    0
```

Final two cents: Please keep the dates consistent and always refer to the [definitions of the SQL platform you use for your schema](https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/sqlite/sqlite-datetime-function).

Comment: Hello, for some reason the first of the month(records) are getting returned as last months record instead of this months

Comment: @Russeljones Is your db only working in your local timezone? Are you able to show us a sample of your current table data with exact datetime stamp as per your schema? Could it be that you have some inconsistency when committing your records to the db?

Comment: I have updated my answer to include the method used to insert a set into the database

Comment: @Russeljones 1) "updated your answer"? you meant to say your question? 2)in your schema you are using a DateTime stamp that is as per the output I have shown in my answer. But why are you using this: `DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    String formattedDate = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(now)`? Do you see that you are inserting `date` values in one format, and then you are trying retrieve them with a different format? Please show **sample data records of your table and what your output data records of conflict**.

Comment: Are you saying im adding the dates a string and trying to retieve them as a date time?

Comment: Im just seeing now in your answer your return sid 2 in both current month and last month, I cant do that as i am comparing the records in both months, I need records from the 2023-05-01 to be only in current month and not in last month

Comment: @Russeljones 1) your table create scheme `date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,`; 2) And your insert statement `DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    String formattedDate = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(now); 'date': formattedDate,` 3) your SELECT query `date BETWEEN datetime('now', 'start of month', 'start of day') AND datetime('now', 'localtime')`; It is vitally important that you provide sample of your table data and query results.

Comment: @Russeljones do you understand the meaning of your this select query? `SELECT * FROM s
WHERE datetime(sdate) BETWEEN
datetime('now','start of month','-1 month') AND
datetime('now','localtime', 'start of month')`

Comment: return records from 01/04/2023 to 1/05/2023, I understand I just need it to stop at 30/04/2023. So is there a way to do minus 1 day or something?

Comment: @Russeljones I have updated answer to incorporate our entire comments, pretty much. I hope that helps you. Good luck!

Comment: it worked by adding -1 day from both this month and last month so for anyone reading if you have built your database the same way I did this is the query that worked for both:     "SELECT * FROM sets WHERE date BETWEEN datetime('now', 'start of month', '-1 day') AND datetime('now', 'localtime');";

Comment: `date` is a keyword but it is not a reserved word.

Answer (score 0):

question isn't super clear, but i'll try to help.

SQLite does not have an official datetime type. Instead, it stores dates and times as TEXT, REAL or INTEGER values using Date and Time Functions.
As far as i can see your schema is using TEXT as ISO8601 strings (“YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS”).

Let's use the following data as a test.

| id | exercise_name | total_weight | total_reps | date | is_favorite |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | current month exercise | 0 | 0 | 2023-05-01 00:00:00 | 0 |
| 2 | last month exercise | 0 | 0 | 2023-04-01 00:00:00 | 0 |
| 3 | very old exercise | 0 | 0 | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | 0 |

Executing the following raw SQL commands should return desired data.

##### LAST MONTH

```
SELECT exercise_name, date(date), time(date) FROM sets WHERE date BETWEEN datetime("2023-04-01") AND datetime("2023-04-30")
```

| exercise_name | date(date) | time(date) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| last month exercise | 2023-04-01 | 00:00:00 |

##### CURRENT MONTH

```
SELECT exercise_name, date(date), time(date) FROM sets WHERE date BETWEEN datetime("2023-05-01") AND datetime("2023-05-31")
```

| exercise_name | date(date) | time(date) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| current month exercise | 2023-05-01 | 00:00:00 |

##### CONSCLUSION

```
SELECT exercise_name, date(date), time(date) FROM sets WHERE date BETWEEN datetime(datetime_start) AND datetime(datetime_end)
```

With static values is obvious, now you can try to execute above statement in yor code to see the outcome. If the outcome is wrong, probably the parameters ***datetime_start*** and ***datetime_end*** are just wrong. If your application runs under different timezones consider applying a Locale/Globalization based on your language offerings. You can give to the parameters any ISO8601 valid string.

Hope it helps,
Hele.

Comment: Oh, as @bonCodigo pointed out `date` is a reserved keyword in sqlite. That's working anyway in my code, but consider moving the column name to **timestamp** or anything else that means something to your logic

Comment: The problem is my Last month also returns the 1st of May it doesnt stop at the 30th of April, While my Current month returns records start at the 2nd of May

Comment: Hele What you think the issue with `datetime` format in the OP's schema in the question?

Comment: Check the **datetime_end** value in your code just before the db call, as you can see in my sample i have a record at 2023-05-01 00:00:00.000 wich is at the very beginning of the month and is not being extracted while asking the records between 2023-04-01 and 2023-04-30

Comment: bonCodigo i didn't get your question

Comment: `date` is a keyword but it is not a reserved word.